# How to connect to a VPN with a certificate using the shipped VPN client within Mac OS X 10.6.6?

Tags: mac-osx, vpn, certificate, keychain

I'm trying to set up a VPN on a Mac OS X to connect to OpenVPN server.
I've been provided the following files:

- client.key
- client.crt
- ta.key
- ca.crt

I added to the Keychain System client.crt & ca.crt, it worked, but when I try to use a certificate in the VPN authentification configuration I get the following error :

> Certificate authentication cannot be
>   used because your keychain does not
>   contain any suitable certificates. Use
>   Keychain Access to import the
>   appropriate certificates into your
>   keychain. If you do not have the
>   certificates required for
>   authentication, contact your network
>   administrator.

Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/no-machine-certificates-found-when-adding-machine-certificate-into-vpn

Comment: See: http://www.securepoint.de/dokumente/How-to_v2007nx_VPN-L2TP-Roadwarrior-MacOSX-e.pdf

Answer (score 5):

This is not going to work. The built-in VPN uses either PPTP or IPSec while OpenVPN uses SSL, both products are not compatible. Use [Tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You've to generate pkcs12 file first and then import it into Keychain access.

You can do that by the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt -out MyPKCS12.p12 -name "Your Name"
```

Then your Keychain access should recognise your certificate.